# Consume a stateful .net web service from java

Tags: java, .net, web-services

In C# I have methods that use

```
   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

I consume them in C# .net by using a cookiecontainer to maintain state.

How do I do the same thing in java?  I want to call a .net webservice with  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] and have it maintain state between calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which SOAP framework you are using. For JAX-WS, you can enable client-side session support by setting `BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY` to true in your request context. You can find an example [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html).